# "So oder so ähnlich" werden junge Leute oft für ihr Benehmen kritisiert

Tags: meaning

> *So oder so ähnlich* werden junge Leute oft für ihr Benehmen kritisiert.

I came across this sentence and the "so oder so ähnlich" part looks weird. Please help me understand what it means exactly in this context. What does it mean literally in English?

Comment: What dictionary did you try and what are you struggling with?

Comment: Ist das "So oder so ähnlich" im Original mit Anführungsstrichen? Fehlt da nicht ein "the" vor dem Zitat, während das "and" dahinter zu viel erscheint? Werden jetzt die jungen Leute mit der Ansage "So oder so ähnlich" kritisiert oder werden sie so oder so ähnlich kritisiert? Mir ist die Frage unklar.

Answer (score 6):

It's "(so) oder (so ähnlich)":

- "so" = "in this way".
- "so ähnlich" = "in a similar way".

By contrast, "so oder so" means "either way" or "in any case".